# Google Cloud Deploy: Parent release failed to render

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-deploy

I am testing new Google Cloud Deploy with my current projects.

I have defined skaffold.yaml, cloudbuild.yaml (using skaffold and gcloud beta deploy), and a basic clouddeploy.yaml.

CI with skaffold and cloud build builds image correctly locally and in the cloud.

But Google Cloud deploy pipeline fails with the error "**Parent release failed to render."** without any more information.

I have checked "skaffold render" and works well for different profiles. is it possible to check some logs about this rendering in google cloud deploy?

Thanks in advance
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can detect any errors in your pipeline runs by using the [Dataflow monitoring interface.](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/dataflow-monitoring-intf)

1. Go to the Google Cloud Console.
2. Select your Google Cloud project from the project list.
3. Click the menu in the upper left corner.
4. Navigate to the Big Data section and click Dataflow. A list of
   running jobs appears in the right-hand pane.
5. Select the pipeline job you want to view. You can see the jobs'
   status at a glance in the Status field: "Running," "Succeeded," or
   "Failed."

To view the **Job Logs** generated by your pipeline code and the Dataflow service, click keyboard_capslock on the bottom **Logs panel**.

You can filter the messages that appear in Job logs by clicking Info-arrow_drop_down and filter_listFilter. To only display error messages, click Info-arrow_drop_down and select Error.

**To expand an error message**, click the expandable section -arrow_right.
Alternatively, you can click the **Diagnostics tab**. This tab shows where errors occurred along the chosen timeline, a count of all logged errors, and possible recommendations for your pipeline.

This [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/troubleshooting-your-pipeline) has a detailed explanation on checking logs for pipelines.

Comment: In Cloud Dataflow console no job appeared.

So notice that Dataflow was not fully enabled for my project, and turn on all the options. After executing a new process in cloud build, the task regarding gcloud deploy gives the following permission error:  loading tarball of [.] to [gs://prevvy1_clouddeploy/source/1633016632.292689-4a46c00eee084e4d88829c2cbaa0dfa0.tgz]
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.deploy.releases.create) PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission 'clouddeploy.releases.create' denied on 'projects/prevvy1/locations/us-central1/deliveryPipelines/frontend/releases/rel-210930-1633016631'

Comment: For **PERMISSION_DENIED** error, Check that the [Dataflow service account](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#cloud_dataflow_service_account) has [Identity and Access Management permissions](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#cloud_dataflow_service_account) to the specific service and [relevant APIs](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/enable-api) are enabled for the project.([source](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors#input_and_output_errors))

Comment: Right now , I don't have any permission error, but when i try to create a release I always got: "Release render operation ended in failure." I don't have any deployment logs in Cloud Deploy. There isn't any job in Dataflow to watch logs.  Dataflow is enabled.  Skaffold render is working fine for any profile in my local or cloudbuild. where could i find logs for this deployment?  Thanks

Comment: `kubectl logs deploy/my-deployment` This command is used to fetch logs of particular deployment. Refer this [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#interacting-with-deployments-and-services) for more information on fetching logs of deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well and the PERMISSION_DENIED comment above helped me out.

To view the logs of Google Cloud Deploy in Cloud Build I found I needed to add permissions to the cloud-deploy service account. This is apparently not done out-of-the-box yet (possibly because it's still in preview so access remains restricted). I didn't find this in the documentation explicitly but it does work to show all the logs of each step cloud deploy runs.

`Inside the Cloud Deploy Project > IAM > Add User > service-${project-NUMBER}@gcp-sa-clouddeploy.iam.gserviceaccount.com > Add Permissions (for proof of concept/solution add Owner)`

Note: that the service account remains hidden (at least in my dashboard) but you can use the gcloud cli to find the account and list all it's permissions.

Rerun the cloud deploy and cloud build should now show you All the logs you need to debug. Mine turned out to be that skaffold only goes to v2beta12 in GCP Cloud Build and my file was on v2beta23.

Answer (score 0):

Render logs are available in the Google Cloud Deploy console interface.

If you click the release in question from the delivery pipeline details page, navigating to the release details page, and then click a rollout where a deployment failed, you will see a 'rollout details' sub-page with a link to the render logs. From there should you be able to inspect the render logs (in Cloud Build) for the render operation, with more details.

You also need, as noted by another, to have `logging.logEntries.create` permissions on the default (or alternate specified) Cloud Deploy service account. More details can be found in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/deploy/docs/cloud-deploy-service-account#execution_service_account).